# How to call parent constructor when a object is instantiated?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

I have this superclass:

```
Class BaseController{
      public function __construct(){
          $this->view = new BaseView();
      }
}
```

and i have 3 classes that extend it. How can i run the constructor function of the base class  without having to put `parent::__construct();` into each constructor method in the child classes?

Comment: You can't... a child class method overrides that of the parent unless you explicity call it... or don't define a __construct() method for your child class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible if you need a child constructor, as stated by the php.net documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the
>   child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
>   parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
>   as private).